# What is the correct naming procedure of text domain, directory and theme name?

Tags: textdomain

This is the example on the WordPress codex:

```
/*
* Theme Name: My Theme
* Author: Theme Author
* Text Domain: my-theme
* Domain Path: /languages
*/
```

Is it possible the for the directory be called "mytheme" or does it have to be "my-theme"?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/

> Themes that are hosted on WordPress.org the text domain must match the
>   slug of your theme URL (wordpress.org/themes/). This is needed
>   so that the translations from translate.wordpress.org work correctly.
>
> The text domain name must use dashes and not underscores and be
>   lowercase. For example, if the theme’s name My Theme is defined in the
>   style.css or it is contained in a folder called my-theme the text
>   domain should be my-theme.